# Make data structure with javascript from data in sql server

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, treeview

I want create dynamic tree view using [angular-ivh-treeview](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview), but it using struct data like:

```
bag = [{
        label: 'Glasses',
        value: 'glasses',
        children: [{
            label: 'Top Hat',
            value: 'top_hat',
            children: [{
                label: 'Black',
                value:'black_hat'
            },
            {
                label: 'Red',
                value: 'red_hat'
            }]
        }, {
            label: 'Curly Mustache',
            value: 'mustachio'
        }]
    }];
```

assuming that i get successful data from database in sql server have structure like

```
id, parentId, label, value
```

How to convert it to data structure above. Please help me!

Comment: data row with no parent id will be on the top and the following child rows will be placed below it.

Comment: post the data sample which you get from the database?

Comment: I know it, but how to find find where to insert into. array in js do not support it

Comment: yes. from parent id and id then make structure like above